# Magento 2.3: Search is not working for specific search terms/queries

Tags: magento2, search-criteria, search-terms

I'm having a strange issue with our website. The issue is that, when I'm searching with some specific keywords like `TV, AC,` It's not giving me the results and its returning empty results as below though we are having the products related to that keywords.

> Your search returned no results

I thought its because of the search keyword length but its not because if I search with different keywords with 2 letters its working fine.

So I have removed the existing query from Search Terms which are AC, TV and created a new with same names but still its returning empty results.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a MYSQL DB setting and not Magento. MYSQL only indexes words that are a certain number of characters in length. So 2 would be too short.

Check this thread
[Magento search less than 4 characters](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/magento-search-less-than-4-characters)

Comment: we can search with 2 letters for other products except the mentioned letters (or) keywords in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Catalog Search Minimal Query Length to 1 or 2 in `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Minimal Query Length`

[image: Like So]

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the sql query from collection then check if its 
Like '%search_term_variable%' 
Instead of 
product_name='search_term_variable';
To print collection you can use it (edit it according to your case)- 
echo $products->getSelect()->__toString();